# Force docker-machine to specific IP using Hyper-V, network unreachable

Tags: hyper-v, docker-machine

[I have found a partial answer to this question](http://I%20have%20found%20a%20partial%20answer%20to%20this%20question), and it is successfully setting the machine at the desired IP address. But the network is unreachable from inside a `docker-machine` created with the Hyper-V driver.

The TLDR on the answer above is to create a script, `/var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh`:

```
sudo cat /var/run/udhcpc.eth0.pid | xargs sudo kill
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.XXX.YYY netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.XXX.255 up
```

Once I make the script, I restart the machine.

When I restart the machine, the IP is set to my desired address (expected). I can remote in at the address, so it is at least available through the host. But when I test for connections, there is no connection to the internet (unexpected).

```
Boot2Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build HEAD : 5ed2840 - Fri May  5 21:04:09 UTC 2017
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be

docker@machine:~$ docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:48331->[::1]:53: read: connection refused

docker@machine:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
```

If I remove the script and restart again, I am reassigned a new/random IP address (expected), remote in at that new IP address, and can do  network connections (expected):

```
docker@pm:~$ docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
aafe6b5e13de: Pull complete
0a2b43a72660: Pull complete
18bdd1e546d2: Pull complete
8198342c3e05: Pull complete
f56970a44fd4: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f3a61450ae43896c4332bda5e78b453f4a93179045f20c8181043b26b5e79028
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest

docker@pm:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=43 time=18.424 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=43 time=27.638 ms
```

The accepted answer has several up votes, but it reads like this is a confirmed work around on VirtualBox. Not sure what about Hyper-V would be causing the IP assignment to cut off internet access.

Comment: Can you docker-machine ssh the machine in each of its states (with/without the script) and for each post the results of the Route command?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by adding the following to the end of bootsync.sh:

```
route add default gw <address>
```

There was no default route to the gateway or the internet, so it must be set manually.